# Incorrect syntax near C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

Estoy insertando datos a una tabla, el primer insert sin problema lo mando (que es el mismo dato) pero en esta parte me manda el error

> Incorrect syntax near '@DescripcionArticulo'

Este es el codigo

```
 private void GrabarDetalles()
        {
            string cnn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["produccion"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection(cnn))
            {
                conexion.Open();
                string sql = ("INSERT INTO DetalleCatalogoAdornos (CodigoArticulo,Descripcion,Cantidad,PrecioActual,Total,DescripcionArticulo) VALUES (@CodigoArticulo,@Descripcion," +
                    "@Cantidad,@PrecioActual,@Total,@DescripcionArticulo");

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conexion);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in GrdArticulos.Rows)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CodigoArticulo", Convert.ToString(row.Cells["CodigoArticulo"].Value));
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Descripcion", Convert.ToString(row.Cells["Descripcion"].Value));
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cantidad", Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["Cantidad"].Value));
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PrecioActual", Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells["PrecioActual"].Value));
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Total", Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells["Total"].Value));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@DescripcionArticulo", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = Convert.ToString(txtDescripcion.Text);

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    MessageBox.Show("Datos Grabados Correctamente", "Informacion", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                }
                conexion.Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Intenta enviar el valor de `@DescripcionArticulo` entre comillas simples, ya que se trata de in `String`, una forma fácil de encontrar un error de este tipo es, con el depurador, o con el `SQL Profiler` para que te muestre la cadena que estas enviando a la DB y así sepas a que campos le faltan comillas simples o cualquier otro error de escritura del query...

Comment: Te falta un paréntesis en `string sql = ... values(....)` Además veo que ese parámetro lo estas enviando con `Add` y no como los demás con `AddWithValue`, prueba así: `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DescripcionArticulo",Convert.ToString(txtDescripcion.Text));` aunque no creo que esto tenga mucho que ver...

Comment: Falta un paréntesis final me parece

Comment: El problema está en la declaración del string, debé empezar string sql = "insert .... values (....)"; y tu tienes paréntesis delante de las camillas dobles y tienes 3 paréntesis que abren y dos que cierran

Comment: Efectivamente... no vi el paréntesis....

Comment: Hola Christian Gtz: Además de lo dicho, para que utilizas el método close de conexion, si lo estas usando en un bloque using, que por defecto, ya va ha realizar el dispose, que a su vez lleva incluido el close. Es innecesario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Muchas gracias por sus comentarios, pero como lo dijo @J.Rodriguez, el error fue por un ) que no estaba cerrando la consulta

```
string sql = ("INSERT INTO DetalleCatalogoAdornos (CodigoArticulo,Descripcion,Cantidad,PrecioActual,Total,DescripcionArticulo) VALUES (@CodigoArticulo,@Descripcion," +
                    "@Cantidad,@PrecioActual,@Total,@DescripcionArticulo)");
```

Comment: Cuanto puedas marca tu propia respuesta como aceptada, para que la pregunta quede como resuelta.

Answer (score 0):

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@DescripcionArticulo", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = Convert.ToString(txtDescripcion.Text);
```

deberia ser:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DescripcionArticulo", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = Convert.ToString(txtDescripcion.Text);
```

Comment: Hola Iria, por favor lea los comentarios en la pregunta. Este no es el problema ni la solución, además la sintaxis usada en : `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DescripcionArticulo", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value ....` No es correcta. No he votado negativamente a tu respuesta, pero esto da paso a que otros usuarios puedan hacerlo.

Comment: sabes la linea del error? el parámetro aparece varias veces

Comment: sigo pensando que el error está en esa línea, no tiendo el = que metes, me da que está mal

Comment: La sintaxis usada en `Add(...)` es correcta, sin embargo la que usaste como `AddWithValue(...)` es incorrecta, mira [mi comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/320339/incorrect-syntax-near-c/320712?noredirect=1#comment581005_320339) en la pregunta, para que veas la sintaxis correcta de .`AddWithValue(...)`